# How do I manipulate a messy table into structured data in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table with columns "Advertiser", "Product", "Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3" with a sales value in each "Week" entry row and would like to convert into a structured table that converts all the week columns into 1 and having the sales value for that corresponding week in a separate column, thus effectively creating a single row for each sales value.

Please see the image URL below clearly showing current vs desired output:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yynz0.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=query(arrayformula(split(flatten(A2:A&"~"&B2:B&"~"&C1:E1&"~"&C2:E),"~")),"where Col2 is not null")
```

[image]